# Robot Framework - Maven / JAVA - reports

Tags: java, maven, report, robotframework

I need to somehow set up our reports that even if there are tests that have passed, and there is one test case that have failed so the whole runner is going to pass as succeed with failure / unstable / warning or something like that.
Cause when I am running our tests through pipeline in AzureDevops its always as a fail. Which is not true.
Can somebody help me ? Thx

I have found a lot of options in python, since the robot framework in python. But we are using Java Maven build.

This is what I got from the pipeline. I would assume that I can somehow configure the reports or the build that is going to be Success, or success with error, unstable or whatever not, just FAILED.

```
Acceptance.Fe.Fe System.Data Manipulation :: Data manipulation tests  | FAIL |
```

2024-02-14T10:26:01.7937901Z 5 tests, 3 passed, 2 failed
2024-02-14T10:26:01.7940524Z ==============================================================================
2024-02-14T10:26:01.8100787Z Acceptance.Fe.Fe System                                               | FAIL |
2024-02-14T10:26:01.8135511Z 5 tests, 3 passed, 2 failed
2024-02-14T10:26:01.8137743Z ==============================================================================
2024-02-14T10:26:01.8277141Z Acceptance.Fe                                                         | FAIL |
2024-02-14T10:26:01.8310474Z 5 tests, 3 passed, 2 failed
2024-02-14T10:26:01.8312553Z ==============================================================================
2024-02-14T10:26:01.8447358Z Acceptance                                                            | FAIL |
2024-02-14T10:26:01.8480212Z 5 tests, 3 passed, 2 failed
2024-02-14T10:26:01.8482676Z ==============================================================================
2024-02-14T10:26:01.8631763Z Output:  /tests/s/target/robotframework-reports/output.xml
2024-02-14T10:26:02.1121207Z XUnit:   /tests/s/target/robotframework-reports/TEST-acceptance.xml
2024-02-14T10:26:02.3598425Z Log:     /tests/s/target/robotframework-reports/log.html
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4322090Z Report:  /tests/s/target/robotframework-reports/report.html
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4544396Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4545887Z [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4547244Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4588173Z [INFO] Total time:  32:03 min
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4590124Z [INFO] Finished at: 2024-02-14T10:26:02Z
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4591510Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4593490Z [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.robotframework:robotframework-maven-plugin:2.1.0:run (default) on project tests: 2 critical test cases failed. Check the logs for details. -> [Help 1]
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4596181Z org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.robotframework:robotframework-maven-plugin:2.1.0:run (default) on project tests: 2 critical test cases failed. Check the logs for details.
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4598424Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:306)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4602276Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4603905Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4605175Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:157)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4606601Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4608114Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4609570Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4611282Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4612502Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4613664Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4614788Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4615933Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4617037Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4618184Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4620474Z     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4621127Z     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4621790Z     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4622368Z     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4622894Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4623493Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4624095Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4624685Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4625281Z Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: 2 critical test cases failed. Check the logs for details.
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4625930Z     at org.robotframework.mavenplugin.RobotFrameworkMojo.evaluateReturnCode (RobotFrameworkMojo.java:69)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4626597Z     at org.robotframework.mavenplugin.AcceptanceTestMojo.subclassExecute (AcceptanceTestMojo.java:68)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4627312Z     at org.robotframework.mavenplugin.AbstractMojoWithLoadedClasspath.execute (AbstractMojoWithLoadedClasspath.java:86)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4628033Z     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4628683Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:301)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4629451Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4630052Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4630653Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:157)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4631301Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4632024Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4632852Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4633565Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4634129Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4634649Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4635171Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4635660Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4636151Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4636632Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4637102Z     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4637662Z     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4638321Z     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4638872Z     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4639410Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4640011Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4640615Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4641194Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4641592Z [ERROR]
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4642437Z [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4642767Z [ERROR]
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4643171Z [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
2024-02-14T10:26:02.4643721Z [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
2024-02-14T10:26:02.7940863Z The process '/usr/bin/mvn' failed with exit code 1
2024-02-14T10:26:02.7941628Z Could not retrieve code analysis results - Maven run failed.
2024-02-14T10:26:02.7973708Z ##[error]Build failed.
2024-02-14T10:26:02.8009801Z ##[section]Finishing: Execute tests

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: ok for example this: